# WSO2 API Mgr-Rest-Query Params

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured a REST API on WSO2 API Manager, which has a Query Param.
When invoked from a subscriber (from API Console), the request is being directed to backend. However, the Query Param that is sent from API Console is not getting reflected in the BE Variable. 
BE API is Java.

**Actual BE URL** :

```
http://localhost:9000/APIMgmtRestFulServiceLengthFinder/testrest/lengthFinder/query?param1=sreedhar
```

**context URL in API Mgr** : `/APIMgmtRestFulServiceLengthFinder/testrest/lengthFinder`

**url pattern in API Mgr** : `/query`

**Sandbox URL** :

`http://localhost:9000/APIMgmtRestFulServiceLengthFinder/testrest/lengthFinder/query?`

Regards, Sreedhar

Comment: How about when you send through a REST client?

Comment: No, it is not happening. I tried from nettools / soap ui.  The Java BE variable for that query param is NOT getting populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got through with above problem. However, I have recreated a fresh REST Project and applied. Following are updated URLs

**Access URL :** http://localhost:9000/UserManagement/rest/UserService/lengthFinder?param1=sreedhar

**Context :** /UserManagement/rest

**URL Pattern :** /UserService/lengthFinder
**Endpoint URL :** http://localhost:9000/UserManagement/rest

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should create your api in API Manager.

1. Give the context as something like "LengthFinder".
2. Define a GET resource /query
3. Add a query parameter to the above resource with the name "param1"
4. Provide http://localhost:9000/APIMgmtRestFulServiceLengthFinder/testrest/lengthFinder/ as the backend url
5. Publish the API, subscribe to it and invoke from the api console and see.

You can invoke it via curl as well to see if there is something wrong when invoked from the api console.

Comment: Hi Amila, I got through and posted as answer.

Comment: Cool. So, what did you have to do different to my answer?

Comment: Well, I have not tried your suggestion. However, the Context that we give is very crucial. Providing any other context seems to be not working. I presume it should be the context of the backend service. (I am not however sure of this). Coming to URL Pattern, I suppose we need to provide THE CONTENT after the CONTEXT. Further, the endpoint would be with protocol://host:port/Context. When I followed this way, it worked. Any other suggestions and improvements, welcome.